# Getting [object Object] when I alert the result I get in my Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

In Ajax JQuery when ever I alert in the Success message I get the alert value as [object Object]

```
success: function(xhr) {

            alert(xhr);
            console.log(xhr);
            $("label#successmessage").text(successmessage);
        }
```

What all I have tried:-

```
SON.stringify(xhr);
console.log(xhr);
even tried with alert(xhr.0)
```

Please help me out

Comment: it is a object that is why its showing object,,just show what you are returning in ajax request.

Comment: the success message gets the data as the first argument  not the `xhr` object...

Comment: you are getting `[object Object]` in the alert because `xhr` is an object.... so its `toString()` returns `[object Object]`. what are you expecting to see here

Comment: see in developer tools that what is shown on console

Comment: JSON.stringify(xhr) should work. but Arun is right, it is a response object.

Comment: as in: alert( JSON.stringify(xhr));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use JSON.stringify(data) in the alert to get anything readable.

Also, $data is a completely different variable name than data.